# Using quarto and revealjs how can I have one word appear on a line on a slide?

Tags: reveal.js, quarto

I would like to have a word appear in a slide rendered with quarto in revealjs format.

I know I can have a word appear on the next line like this:

```
---
title: "Thoughts on Quarto"
format:
  revealjs
---

## Why do I use Quarto?


Because Excel 

:::{.fragment}
stinks
:::
```

but I want the new word to appear on the same line. Is that possible without making two nearly identical slides (and perhaps using `auto-animate=true`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the whole line (with fragments) within a pandoc divs (`::::`) and then set `display: flex` for the div and to make some space between the fragments, set some padding.

```
---
title: "Thoughts on Quarto"
format:
  revealjs:
    css: inline_fragment.css
---

## Why do I use Quarto?

:::: {.inline-fragment}

Because Excel 

:::{.fragment}
stinks
:::

::: {.fragment}
YESSSS!!!
:::

::::
```

**inline_fragment.css**

```
.inline-fragment {
  display: flex;
}

.inline-fragment p {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

**output**

---

[image: initial]

---

[image: fragment one]

---

[image: fragment two]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `[your-text]{.fragment}` for inline fragment:

```
---
title: "Thoughts on Quarto"
format:
  revealjs
---

## Why do I use Quarto?

Because Excel [stinks]{.fragment} [YESSS!!!]{.fragment}
```